# UDP header is filled more than what it is meant to be (42)

Tags: c++, udp, wireshark

I am trying to send out data in UDP format (without handing any error - just opening the socket and send data). The code used is as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in client;

    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[1206]();
    for(auto i=0; i<1206; i++){
       buffer[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);
    }

    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port = htons(5005);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    socklen_t m = sizeof(client);
    while(true){
         sendto(sockfd,buffer,1206 ,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,m);
         cout<<"\nMessage sent...!! \n";  
     }  
}
```

However, this is not being recognized as UDP protocol. When tried to capture it using wireshark, I get following result. (1206 bytes of buffered data as expected but 44 bytes of header which should be 42). What is the problem with the code?

[image]

Comment: Your code works as-is on my machine (CentOS 7 with gcc 4.8.5)

Comment: Does it make any difference ? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with clang 7.0

Comment: Why don't you browse the header contents in wireshark to get more details? Note that UDP header isn't fixed, since it has options.

Comment: It is displaying all other protocol names under protocol section (also udp sent from other modules). Only data sent from the code snippet I posted is not being displayed as UDP

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine (tested on CentOS 7 with gcc 4.8.5). The capture method you are using is removing the Ethernet, IP and UDP layers, leaving you only with the payload.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? I am new to networking protocols.

Comment: @Shloim is exactly right. Whichever way you are calling `tshark`, `tcpdump`, or $capturingProgram, make it so that it captures all of the relevant layers. More info on [capture deconstruction](https://tshark.dev/formats/pcap_deconstruction/). This article on the [OSI model](https://www.plixer.com/blog/network-layers-explained/) isn't terrible.

Comment: @Skanda That depends. How do you capture the packets?

Comment: I have no idea on configurations. All I do is specify the port number in the wireshark and start listening. Also I observed that Time in wireshark change only after a second but I need something with micro second or at-least millisecond precision.  Could any one help me with configuration of receiver to record time and also header with 42 bytes (If this is mandatory)

Comment: are you running wireshark as root?

Comment: Yes. I am running wireshark as root.